Error message while trying to knit an R Markdown
I'm trying to run an R Markdown in RStudio, but when I click "Knit", the following message appears:
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'Matrix' 1.5-4.1 is being loaded, but >= 1.6.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Ejecución interrumpida

It seems like an update of the package "Matrix" is needed, but when I try to do it by using the command
install.packages("Matrix")
the following message appears:
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

I have already installed Rtools (correctly, I figure) and restarted RStudio. I don't know where the source of the problem is.

If you have installed Rtools but R can't find it, see this FAQ: RTools not detected by R. Check that your Rtools version is correct, and then make sure it is on your system path.

It sounds as though you're on Windows and using an obsolete version of R.  The simplest solution is to update R, then you won't need to build Matrix, you can download a binary version.
